Where can Non-Constructibility be placed in the Analytical Hierarchy?
In this question I am interested in non constructible sets, which are sets that are outside  $L$ which is the constructible universe.
These sets  exist   in theories that assume axioms that state that other universes such as $V$ or $HOD$ are bigger than $L$ and so they contain sets that are not in $L$, the negation of the axiom of constructibility.
One of such sets is zero sharp: $0^{\sharp}$.
Let us consider a set $S_{NC}$ defined as the set of  Gödel numbers of the definable and non constructible sets (like $0^{\sharp}$ for instance). Where does $S_{NC}$ belong to in the analytical hierarchy?

Why do you think $S_{NC}$ is in the analytical hierarchy at all? At a glance, $S_{NC}$ seems to invoke the machinery of second-order set theory by assuming you have a function which maps a set-theoretic formula to the set it defines. Due to Tarski's undefinability theorem, such a map cannot be defined in the first-order language of set theory, let alone in second-order arithmetic which is much less expressive.

Relatedly, why do you think nonconstructible sets (like $0^{#}$) exist at all? Set theorists at large haven't come to a consensus on whether $V=L$ should be true or false, and many see it as subjective. Assuming $V\neq L$ opens you up to a plethora of possible set-theoretic universes, so you can't hope to characterize $S_{NC}$ without being specific about your assumptions. If you assume $V=L$ then $S_{NC}=\emptyset$ is trivially at the bottom of the analytical hierarchy.

I didn't think $S_{NC}$ was necessarily an analytic set. I was just waiting for an answer to confirm or refute that.

I am aware that the negation of the  axioms of constructibility gives rise to many possible universes,  initially I wanted to restrict the universe to $HOD$, but then I decided  to drop that and  see the answers I could get.

First let me answer the question "How complicated is the set of (non)constructible reals?" as I would reflexively understand it. A real $r$ is constructible iff it is an element of some well-founded countable model of $\mathsf{KP+V=L}$. This is a $\Sigma^1_2$ condition; that is, $\mathbb{R}\cap L$ is guaranteed to be a $\Sigma^1_2$ set. (It's worth distinguishing lightface and boldface notions here; e.g. in the presence of large cardinals, $\mathbb{R}\cap L$ is ${\bf \Sigma^0_2}$ (since it's countable) and $\Sigma^1_2$ but not $\Delta^1_2$. So the lightface and boldface complexity levels can be very far apart.

However, this does not answer your question as posed. This is because of how you've chosen to represent and focus on definable reals. For example, for each $k\in\omega$ let $$\chi_k=\{n: 2^{\aleph_{\omega\cdot k+2n}}=2^{\aleph_{\omega\cdot k+2n+1}}\}$$ be the real coded into the $k$th "block" of the continuum pattern. Any $A\subseteq\omega$ could be the set of $k$ such that $\chi_k\not\in L$, so your question as phrased cannot actually be answered.
Under reasonable assumptions we can even - as suggested by Jade Vanadium above - have a model $M$ such that "$S_{NC}$ in the sense of $M$" is not actually an element of $M$.

The second part of your answer is not  clear to me.  Do you mean that any infinite set of natural numbers could code a la Gödel the set of definable  non constructible reals?

@holmes Not quite - I mean that any set of natural numbers, finite or infinite, could be the set $X$ of $k$ such that $\chi_k$ happens to define a nonconstructible real. Since this set is easily extractable from $S_{NC}$, that means $S_{NC}$ can be arbitrarily complicated. (Short version: any set can be $X$, and $X$ is reducible to $S_{NC}$.)

if any set can be reduced to $S_{NC}$ does not this fact alone imply that $S_{NC}$ is not a set of the Analytical hierarchy ?

@holmes You have to remember that $S_{NC}$ is model-dependent. E.g. if $V=L$ then $S_{NC}=\omega$, which is even computable. The point of my answer is that there is no a priori upper bound on the complexity of $S_{NC}$. So in some models, $S_{NC}$ is (for instance) not analytic, etc.

I think this answers my question. One more thing can we say what the complexity of  $S_{NC}$ is when the universe is $HOD$ and $HOD\neq L$?

@holmes No, the coding-into-the-continuum-pattern trick still works.

Last thing, about the comment of Jade Vanadium, under which assumptions $S_{NC}$ is not an element of $M$?
